# How to create graphics when using classes? AS3

Tags: image, actionscript-3, apache-flex, components

I am creating a "game" of sorts where three different colored circles appear on the screen and take different amounts of clicks to make disappear. I have a main mxml function and then 4 other classes. I thought I was close to finishing it, but I have encountered an error and it is not telling me what it is. Here is a link to the rubric [here](http://mypage.iu.edu/~tfaas/222/assignments/project1.html) The error I get when I run the code is: "Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: file:///C|/Users/Gabe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.6/Project 1/bin-debug/framework_4.6.0.23201.swf"  Here is my code:

main.mxml:

```
import com.multiClicker.*;

        import spark.components.Image;

        //create the init function
        public function init():void {
            //create new target and add it to the stage
            onEnterFrame();

        }

        public function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void{
            //2% chance of being added per frame
            if(Math.random() <= .02) {
                //33% chance of adding red target
                if(Math.random() <= .033){
                    //make a new image
                    var newCircle1:RedTarget = new RedTarget();

                    this.addElement(newCircle1);

                    //position circle 
                    newCircle1.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                    newCircle1.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                }
                //33% chance of adding blue target
                else if(Math.random() > .066){
                    //make a new image
                    var newCircle2:BlueTarget = new BlueTarget();

                    this.addElement(newCircle2);

                    //position circle 
                    newCircle2.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                    newCircle2.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                }
                //33% chance of adding green target
                else {
                    //make a new image
                    var newCircle3:GreenTarget = new GreenTarget();

                    this.addElement(newCircle3);

                    //position circle 
                    newCircle3.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                    newCircle3.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                }

            }
        }
```

my Target.as file:

```
package com.multiClicker{

//import the needed classes
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;

import spark.components.Image;

public var hp:Number;

public class Target extends Image 
{

    public function Target() {

        //add event listeners
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

    }

    //sets the hp of the target
    public function hP():Number { 
        return hp;
    }

    //get function that returns false if alpha is <= 0
    public function dead():Boolean {

        if(alpha <= 0){
            return false;
        }

    }

    //subtracts one from targets HP when clicked
    public function onClick(e:MouseEvent = null):void {


        //subtracts one from hp each click
        hp--;

        if(hp <=0) {
            this.addEventListener(onEnterFrame);
        }

    }

    //subtracts .1 from the classes alpha
    public function onEnterFrame(e:Timer):void{
        this.alpha =- .1;
    }

    //draws the target
    public function drawTarget(color):void {

        var circle:Shape = new Shape();

        circle.graphics.beginFill(color);
        circle.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,30);

    }

}
```

}

then the target files Red, Blue, and GreenTarget.as which are all the same:

```
package com.multiClicker{   
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class RedTarget extends Target
{

    private var hp:Number = 3;

    public function RedTarget()
    {
        //draw the red circle
        this.graphics.beginFill(0x990000);
        this.graphics.drawCircle(0,0,30);

        //include the super function
        super();
    }

    //subtracts one from targets HP when clicked
    override public function onClick(e:MouseEvent=null):void {

        super.onClick(e);

        //subtracts one from hp each click
        hp--;

        if(hp <=0) {
            this.addEventListener(onEnterFrame);
        }

    }

}
```

}

I am getting an error in Target and GreenTarget only. It is not telling me what the error is or where. any help would be awesome!

edit: I posted the error message I was getting. I used the clean function on Flash Builder and it erased my errors. Then I go to run it again and I get a file not found error. It says my Main.swf cannot be found.

edit2: I think I found the error, I deleted my onEnterFrame function in my Main.mxml file and the errors went away. Now I just do not see what is wrong with that function.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the error message. I've yet to see an error that doesn't at least _hint_ about what's gone wrong. Is it a compile-time error or a run-time error? Is the error triggered by any interaction?

Comment: Just copy/paste the error. Alternatively, run it in a debugger and see what comes up.

Comment: There is no error on any line. But I will edit the question for the error I get when I run it.

Comment: The error message implies that when you run the SWF locally, it has trouble downloading one of the Flex Framework RSL's. It's unrelated to your code, and more related to how you're running the SWF in your local environment. Wish I could help more.

Comment: I figured out its my onEnterFrame function in my Main.mxml file. Is there a better way to structure it so it does not give me these errors?

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar using MiniBuilder:

http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1360282440

Here are the classes:

Application.as

```
package com.multiClicker {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class Application extends Sprite {
    public function
    Application() {
        addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame );
    }

    private function
    onEnterFrame( e:Event ):void {
        var circle:Target;
        var n:Number = Math.random();

        // 33% of 2% chance each of being added per frame
        if ( n <= 0.00667 )     circle = new RedTarget();
        else if( n <= 0.01334 ) circle = new GreenTarget();
        else if( n <= 0.02 )    circle = new BlueTarget();

        if ( circle ) {
            circle.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
            circle.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
            addChild( circle );
        }

        // Remove dead
        for ( var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++ ) {
            var child:Target = getChildAt( i ) as Target;
            if ( child ) {
                if ( child.dead ) {
                    removeChild( child );
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Target.as

```
package com.multiClicker {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class Target extends Sprite {
    protected var hp:Number;

    public function 
    Target() {
        addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick );
    }

    public function
    get dead():Boolean {
        if ( alpha <= 0 ) return true;
        return false;
    }

    protected function
    drawTarget( color:uint ):void {
        graphics.beginFill( color );
        graphics.drawCircle( 0, 0, 30 );
        graphics.endFill();
    }

    private function 
    onClick( e:MouseEvent = null ):void {
       if ( --hp <= 0 ) addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame );
    }

    private function 
    onEnterFrame( e:Event ):void{
        alpha -= 0.1;
        if ( alpha <= 0 ) {
            removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame );
            removeEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick );
        }
    }
}
}
```

RedTarget.as

```
package com.multiClicker {
public class RedTarget extends Target {
    public function
    RedTarget() {
        super();
        hp = 3;
        drawTarget( 0xff0000 );
    }
}
}
```

GreenTarget.as

```
package com.multiClicker {
public class GreenTarget extends Target {
    public function
    GreenTarget() {
        super();
        hp = 2;
        drawTarget( 0x00ff00 );
    }
}
}
```

BlueTarget.as

```
package com.multiClicker {
public class BlueTarget extends Target {
    public function
    BlueTarget() {
        super();
        hp = 1;
        drawTarget( 0x0000ff );
    }
}
}
```

I hope that helps.